# OnClick get "id" attribute of "a" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-mobile

I have list view in jQuery Mobile web app this list view is made of elements like this:

```
<li id='search_r'>
    <a href='#' id='$id' class='s_result'></a>
</li>
<li id='search_r'>
    <a href='#' id='$id' class='s_result'></a>
</li>
```

Number of element depends on number of search results, its not only these two.
When I click on element in list view, in this case:

```
<li></li>
```

I need 2 things to happen, one is to assign the 'id' attr from "a" tag inside this specific "li" tag (the clicked one), to the global variable I have called 'search_r'. The click event works fine, but to get attribute from "a" tag I can't manage to do.

Here is my js:

```
$("#cc_page").ready(function(){
  $("#search_r").live('click', function(){
      search_r = $(this).attr('id');
      window.location.href = "http://imes.********.com/app/userpanel.html#sfpp_page";
  });
});
```

I know "this" is not solution. I'm really new to js so that's why I'm asking such an ridiculous questions :)

Comment: Multiple `id='search_r'` are a **no-no**.

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: Actually tried to use .on() with no luck. And in jQuery 1.8.2 it works just fine.

Comment: Although in next prototype I'll try to tidy all my js and php files only with newest and not deprecated functions and methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem you've got is duplicate `search_r` id attributes, which is invalid. These should be changed to classes. Also, you should be using `on()` with a delegate handler, as `live()` has been removed from the latest version of jQuery. Try this:

```
<li class='search_r'>
    <a href='#' id='$id' class='s_result'></a>
</li>
<li class='search_r'>
    <a href='#' id='$id' class='s_result'></a>
</li>
```

```js
$("#cc_page").on('click', '.search_r', function(){
    var search_r = $('a', this).attr('id');
    console.log(search_r); // just to check it works

    // I assume this is just for testing, otherwise leaving the page 
    // immediately on click renders getting the id completely moot.
    //window.location.href = "http://imes.********.com/app/userpanel.html#sfpp_page";
});
```

I also assume the `$id` in your HTML is from some form of templating engine which gets interpreted? If not, those will also need to be made unique.

Answer (score 1):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated in jQuery since v1.7, and has been removed in v1.9.

You should replace it with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

`.on` has 2 syntaxes for binding elements, whereas `.live` only had 1.

If the element exists at the time you are binding, you do it like this:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(){
    .......
});
```

You can even use the shorthand:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    .........
});
```

If the element does not exist at the time, or new ones will be added (which is what `.live` was normally used for), you need to use "event delegation":

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function(){
    .............
});
```

NOTE: You want to bind to the closest static element, not always `document`.

In the meantime, the [**jQuery Migrate plugin**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) can be used to restore the `.live()` functionality if you upgrade your jQuery to the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` causes the browser to make a new request. Any variables will be reset when the new page loads.

What is your goal with `search_r`?

Comment: I'm trying to assign this value to the global variable: search_r, so After clicking on result, new page will be opened and id in global variable will be used to load data needed for this new page.

Comment: The scope of a global variable is limited to one request/response. If you need to keep the value longer than that you should consider something like passing it to the new page through the query string or perhaps even changing things around a bit more to use Ajax.

Comment: I am using ajax on next page to load information about db record found by id, but I just can't find a way to pass it. I mean to pass id from that link into next page. With php would be easy, but because I need to keep all my files .html I really can't use php methods.